# Problem With extracting dates using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, extract

I was just extracting data from an api but here's the problem that i am facing right now.
the code is following:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

title=[]
overview=[]
popularity=[]
release_date=[]
vote_count=[]
vote_average=[]
adult=[]
original_language=[]
for i in np.arange(1, 3):
  # replace <<my_api_key>> with your key
  url = f'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=<<my_api_key>>&language=en-US&page={i}'
  output = requests.get(url).json()
  needed_output = output['results']
  for val in needed_output:
    title.append(val['title'])
    overview.append(val['overview'])
    popularity.append(val['popularity'])
    vote_count.append(val['vote_count'])
    vote_average.append(val['vote_average'])
    original_language.append(val['original_language'])
    adult.append(val['adult'])
    release_date.append(val['release_date'])
```

when i tried to fetch the data for a single page it worked fine but when i used loop and tried to fetch data for 3 pages, it caused following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-41-68206e98ef80> in <cell line: 9>()
     19     original_language.append(val['original_language'])
     20     adult.append(val['adult'])
---> 21     release_date.append(val['release_date'])

KeyError: 'release_date'
```

any solutions?

i was trying to ask a question and i am expecting to get a worthy answer

Comment: How does the structure of the data returned from the API differ with the two request types?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [API documentation here](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-popular-movies), it looks like the `release_date` field is an optional field in the response. In fact, all the response fields are optional. Therefore, your code shouldn't assume that there will be an `release_date` in the response all the time. In Python, you can do it in two ways:

1. Check if key exists before you use it:

You can check if the `release_date` exists in your `val` variable using:

```
if "release_date" in val:
    release_date.append(val['release_date'])
```

2. Use `.get()`

Python dictionaries support a function called `get` which returns None if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary. An example:

```
release_date.append(val.get("release_date"))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you may see here:
https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-popular-movies
in section "response" field `release_date` is optional as other fields, but by `val['release_date']` you are assuming key will be there for sure, better would be accessing value by `val.get('release_date', '')`